# How are `:~@` and `:!@` parsed?

Tags: ruby, symbols, literals

When I write `:~@` and `:!@`, they are evaluated to `:~` and `:!`, which can be achieved also by writing `:~` and `:!`. How are these expressions parsed, and where did the `@` go?

Comment: @engineersmnky, I think it refers to a symbol.

Comment: You might want to note that `:-@` works as expected but `:!@` doesn't and that `-@` is the unary negation method but `!@` isn't a method.

Comment: According to ruby_parser it goes nowhere: `RubyParser.new.parse(":~@") # => s(:lit, :~)`

Comment: `:~` is a Symbol, and `@` is the beginning of an instance variable. Maybe it's absorbed into whatever's coming after that? Like `:~@x`.

Comment: @tadman It is subtler than that as `@` doesn't always mean "instance variable", sometimes it means "unary method". I'm guessing that this is a parser bug related to some kludge for allowing the symbols for unary operators to be parsed without requiring quotes.

Comment: @muistooshort It's certainly an odd one. I think this is a bug in the parser somewhere, some edge case that's not normally triggered, as an error should be emitted. In `irb` it will wait for additional input after the `@`. `:"~@"` works as expected.

Comment: @tadman A bug specifically related to a kludge for unary methods. `:+@` and `:-@` seem to work fine but other "non-alpha followed by @" exercise the bug.

Comment: I just filed [a bug report](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10463).

Answer (score 1):

It's to do with precedence in the parser.  A simple dash defeats the colon-means-a-symbol syntax, too:

```
2.1.2 :004 > c = :test-thing
NameError: undefined local variable or method `thing' for main:Object
```

It's easy enough to work around it, though: try `:'~@'`,

(Of course, if you can avoid creating such a weird symbol in your code, that might be a better idea...)

Comment: If it is parsed like that, then there is no problem. The problem is that it is silently parsed as a different thing. And, it is not a weird symbol. It is a method name, and it should also be the return value of method definition of such method.

Comment: @sawa -- I certainly think it should raise an error, as in my 'thing' example. By "weird" I only meant that '@' has a specific ruby meaning, the prefix for a class attribute, and as such I imagine the parser is treating it as a special case.